# Give a value to 'NoneType' span title with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
surface = calendar_containers[0].findAll('td', class_ = 's-color')
    for i in surface:
        surfaces.append(i.find('span')['title'])
```

which I am using to retrieve span titles from a site I want to scrape.

The code is returning a list of elements until it runs into one element which doesn't have a span title and then returns "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

I would like to know if it was possible to make the script just append a text like "None" everytime it is running into a 'Nonetype' and continue appending the next elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
surface = calendar_containers[0].findAll('td', class_ = 's-color')
for i in surface:
    try:
        surfaces.append(i.find('span')['title'])
    except TypeError:
        surfaces.append('None')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but you're probably better off replacing, `surfaces.append(i.find('span')['title'])` with:

```
cont = i.find('span')
title = cont['title'] if cont else 'None'
surfaces.append(title)
```

Comment: Thank you. The code you provided worked as intended.